# onClickListener with CardView

Tags: android, cardview

У меня есть onClickListener для всей CardView. Но на эту CardView хочу еще другие лисэнэры подключить, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищите `id` нужного элемента, к нему и прикрепляйте.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?